# How run two or more instances of an oracle job in the same time?

Tags: oracle, plsql, scheduler, jobs

I have defined a function that when it is called it will define an oracle job with

**dbms_scheduler.create_job**

that runs a store_procedure with arguments

```
my Function
Begin
    job created and executed from here
end;
```

My problem is that when an instance of my job is executing I can not execute another instance of that job.
as I said my jobs executes a store_procedure that have arguments so I want to execute that job with different values of arguments in the same time but I can not.
is there any property or way that can help me to do this?

Comment: Post the entire code you have written so far. This pseudo code is not very useful to help you.

Comment: It is a concept there is no need to post the code ,although I cant access the code from home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the jobs you create random names.

Comment: thanks it was helpful. I used dbms_scheduler.generate_job_name function for that.