# How to create a async Oracle job to run in multiple instances

Tags: oracle, scheduler, oracle12c, job-scheduling

I have created the next program and subsequent Oracle JOB:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_program (program_name          => 'myProg',
                                  program_action        => 'myProc',
                                  program_type          => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
                                  number_of_arguments   => 3,
                                  enabled               => FALSE);

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_PROGRAM_ARGUMENT (program_name        => 'myProg',
                                           argument_position   => 1,
                                           argument_type       => 'NUMBER');

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_PROGRAM_ARGUMENT (program_name        => 'myProg',
                                           argument_position   => 2,
                                           argument_type       => 'NUMBER');

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_PROGRAM_ARGUMENT (program_name        => 'myProg',
                                           argument_position   => 3,
                                           argument_type       => 'NUMBER',
                                           DEFAULT_VALUE       => NULL);

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job ('myJob',
                              program_name   => 'myProg',
                              enabled        => FALSE,
                              comments       => 'Send data');

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE ('myJob', 'PARALLEL_INSTANCES', TRUE);
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE ('myJob',
                                 'logging_level',
                                 DBMS_SCHEDULER.LOGGING_FULL);
END;
/
```

Now, I have a user who can run/execute jobs that calls the next procedure:

```
    PROCEDURE runJOB(param1   IN PLS_INTEGER,
                  param2   IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
                  param3   IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT NULL)
IS
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable ('myProg');

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('myJob', 1, TO_CHAR (param1));
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('myJob', 2, TO_CHAR (param2));
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('myJob', 3, TO_CHAR (param3));
   --DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable ('myJob');
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB (JOB_NAME => 'myJob', USE_CURRENT_SESSION => FALSE);
--DBMS_SCHEDULER.disable ('myJob');
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);
END runJOB;
```

What are my problems here?

- I need to run the job in asynchronous mode. That's why I have a
  `enable` or a `run_job` using the `USE_CURRENT_SESSION` parameter
  `FALSE`. I think this works.
- I need to execute multiple instances of the same job, starting by
  different users, at the same time. For example, user A calls the
  `runJOB` procedure. The job can run in 20 seconds. In this 20
  seconds, user B can call the same procedure, in a different session.
  That's why I've tried to use the `PARALLEL_INSTANCES` attribute, but
  I get only one execution. I think Oracle sees that the job is
  running, so discard the second attempt to run.

In resuming, I need a job that must be executed in async mode and with multiple instances at the same time.

After a "double" execution of the job for two instances I only get one record in `user_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS` table, but 2 enable job's for two different users (SGSS and EX01882_BD)

```
52367532    26/12/2016 12:08:44,584878 +00:00   SGSS    myJob DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS RUN SUCCEEDED                               (HugeClob)
52364238    26/12/2016 12:08:36,529539 +00:00   SGSS    myJob DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS ENABLE      EX01882_BD                          (HUGECLOB)
52367534    26/12/2016 12:08:34,302807 +00:00   SGSS    myJob DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS ENABLE      SGSS                            (HUGECLOB)
```

Any help?

**Note:** 
I cannot have job's different names as in this solution ([How run two or more instances of an oracle job in the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127039/how-run-two-or-more-instances-of-an-oracle-job-in-the-same-time?rq=1)), because the job is already created and the users who call this job don't have permissions to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: [Event-Based Jobs](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-enhancements-10gr2#event_based_jobs)

```
GRANT AQ_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE TO USERA;
GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_SCHEDULER TO USERA;
GRANT EXECUTE ON sys.DBMS_SCHEDULER TO USERA;
GRANT EXECUTE ON sys.DBMS_ISCHED TO USERA;
GRANT CREATE JOB TO USERA;
GRANT CREATE EXTERNAL JOB TO USERA;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_event_queue_payload AS OBJECT (
  event_name  VARCHAR2(30)
);

BEGIN
   -- Create a queue table to hold the event queue.
   DBMS_AQADM.create_queue_table (
      queue_table          => 'event_queue_tab',
      queue_payload_type   => 't_event_queue_payload',
      multiple_consumers   => TRUE,
      comment              => 'Comments');

   --Create the event queue.
   DBMS_AQADM.create_queue (queue_name    => 'event_queue',
                            queue_table   => 'event_queue_tab');

   -- Start the event queue.
   DBMS_AQADM.start_queue (queue_name => 'event_queue');
END;
/


BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_program (
      program_name          => 'myProg',
      program_action        => 'USERA.PACKAGE.myProc',
      program_type          => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
      number_of_arguments   => 3,
      enabled               => FALSE);

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_PROGRAM_ARGUMENT (program_name        => 'myProg',
                                           argument_position   => 1,
                                           argument_type       => 'NUMBER');

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_PROGRAM_ARGUMENT (program_name        => 'myProg',
                                           argument_position   => 2,
                                           argument_type       => 'NUMBER');

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_PROGRAM_ARGUMENT (program_name        => 'myProg',
                                           argument_position   => 3,
                                           argument_type       => 'NUMBER',
                                           DEFAULT_VALUE       => NULL);

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable ('myProg');
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
      'myJob',
      program_name      => 'myProg',
      comments          => 'StartJob',
      auto_drop         => FALSE,
      start_date        => SYSTIMESTAMP,
      event_condition   => 'tab.user_data.event_name = ''give_me_a_prod''',
      queue_spec        => 'event_queue',
      enabled           => FALSE);

   COMMIT;
END;
/

PROCEDURE enqueue(param1   IN PLS_INTEGER,
                  param2   IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
                  param3   IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT NULL)
IS
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
   l_enqueue_options      DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
   l_message_properties   DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
   l_message_handle       RAW (16);
   l_queue_msg            t_event_queue_payload;
BEGIN
   l_queue_msg := t_event_queue_payload ('give_me_a_prod');

   -- Define arguments
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('myJob', 1, TO_CHAR (param1));
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('myJob', 2, TO_CHAR (param2));
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('myJob', 3, TO_CHAR (param3));

   DBMS_AQ.enqueue (queue_name           => 'USERA.event_queue',
                    enqueue_options      => l_enqueue_options,
                    message_properties   => l_message_properties,
                    payload              => l_queue_msg,
                    msgid                => l_message_handle);

   COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         SQLERRM || ' - ' || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);
END enqueue;
```

In Package:

```
PROCEDURE myProc(param1   IN PLS_INTEGER,
                  param2   IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
                  param3   IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT NULL)
IS
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
...
   PKG_SAP_FSCD_INTERRECIBOS.callSomething.... 
...

END myProc;
```

Answer (score 2):

> DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB (JOB_NAME => 'myJob', USE_CURRENT_SESSION =>
>   **FALSE**);

now, check [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72395):

> This specifies whether or not the job run should occur in the same
>   session that the procedure was invoked from.
>
> When use_current_session is set to TRUE:
>
> - The job runs as the user who called RUN_JOB, or in the case of a    local external job with a credential, the user named in the
>     credential.
> - You can test a job and see any possible errors on the command line.
> - run_count, last_start_date, last_run_duration, and failure_count are    not updated.
> - **RUN_JOB can be run in parallel with a regularly scheduled job run.**
>
> When use_current_session is set to FALSE:
>
> - The job runs as the user who is the job owner.
> - You need to check the job log to find error information.
> - run_count, last_start_date, last_run_duration, and failure_count are updated.
> - **RUN_JOB fails if a regularly scheduled job is running.**

Comment: Thanks, but using FALSE is what which I had already reported. I need to start a new job instance even if one other instance is running. Let me try the TRUE value with a little change here.

Comment: If I use TRUE I cannot have async job execution. With FALSE I cannot have multiple executions of the same job

Comment: Yep, if you need really parallel execution u should read about Queues (for example: https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-enhancements-10gr2)